# Works on iOS Simulator but not on iOS device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

EDIT: It works but it takes amazingly long to complete. 
Is this normal, or is there a way to optimize it?

Thanks

I am using DDUnitConverter in my project to convert currencies.

Everything works perfectly fine on the iOS Simulator but hangs when I try to convert the currencies on my iOS Device (iPhone 4  iOSv5.1). I looked around to find a fix to this issue but could not find anything. Here is the code that I use to exchange the currencies. The code within the DDUnitConverter is available here: https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter/downloads

```
if ([Number.text isEqualToString:@""] || [picklable.text isEqualToString:@"no selection"] || [picklable2.text isEqualToString:@"no selection"]) {
    return;
}

if ([Number.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    Result.text = @"0";
    return;
}

int fromType;
int toType;

fromType = [list indexOfObject:picklable.text];
toType = [list indexOfObject:picklable2.text];

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * from = [[f numberFromString:Number.text] retain];
[f release];

NSNumber *to = [[[DDUnitConverter currencyUnitConverter] convertNumber:from fromUnit:fromType toUnit:toType] retain];
float toto = [to floatValue];
Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f %@", toto, picklable2.text];

if ((toto == 0 || toto == [Number.text floatValue]) && picklable.text != picklable2.text ) {
    Result.text = @"No Internet Connection or Previous Data";
}

[from release];
[to release];

[Result flashScrollIndicators];
```

Hopefully someone can help me out,
Thanks

Comment: Hanging can mean a loop that's gone crazy, hanging can mean a crash, hanging can mean a crazy dispatch.  Hanging is too vague!  CRASH LOGS PLEASE.

Comment: it doesn't crash, and i'm pretty sure there are no loops

Comment: If it is a web service, then there's nothing you can do.  If it's local, you can dispatch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems OK to me, but you are using DDUnitConverter. I've never used it, but I suppose it needs internet connection to load data from the internet. If the server take long time to answer, your app could hang on connection.

You can try to connect to the server asynchronously using `dispatch_async`, this lets your app download data in background.

Comment: Have you tried to remove NSNumber *to = [[[DDUnitConverter currencyUnitConverter] convertNumber:from fromUnit:fromType toUnit:toType] retain]; from your code? Does this make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Anything taking amazingly long to do should be dispatched.  Like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self doReallyAmazinglyComplicatedProcessing];
});
```

Comment: haha, alright thanks I will try that "doReallyAmazinglyComplicatedProcessing" ;) thanks though